# Sacar Palabras De Un Texto

Tags: c#

Tengo un string con datos y lo que quiero hacer es sacar palabras deseadas Que tengan caracteres específicos para luego agregar cada palabra a una matriz[] con datos sacados del texto

```
string datos = "Hay datos <Etiqueta>que [re]quiero <Etiqueta>Hola que tal";
```

En este string quiero sacar las palabras que están después de <Etiqueta> y hasta se encuentre el espacio

En Este caso el resultado que quiero obtener seria:

```
string[] Datos = new string[2];

        Datos[0] = "que";
        Datos[1] = "Hola";
```

Comment: siempre es así: <Etiqueta>que o es <Etiqueta> que (nótese el espacio)

Comment: Para publicar una pregunta no permite escribir <Etiqueta> en el texto...

Comment: No creo que esté bien definido qué caracteres pueden estar luego de la `<Etiqueta>`. ¿Sólo letras, otros caracteres, cualquier caracter que no sea un espacio? Además, ¿el texto de la etiqueta es siempre "Etiqueta", o varía? ¿Puede haber etiquetas con diferente nombre en el texto? ¿Para qué estás haciendo esto? ¿Cuál es el objetivo? ¿Por qué se está buscando este texto? ¿Para reemplazarlo? ¿Para marcarlo? ¿Qué se hará con las palabras obtenidas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede tratar de usar [`Regex`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expresi%C3%B3n_regular) le dejo una forma de emplearla que creo que es lo que busca:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

.

```
       string pattern = @"<Etiqueta>(?<despues>\w+)";

        string input = @"<Hay datos <Etiqueta>que [re]quiero <Etiqueta>Hola que tal";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

        for (int i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("despues de <Etiqueta>:" + matches[i].Groups["despues"].ToString());
        }
```

Salida:

```
despues de <Etiqueta>:que
despues de <Etiqueta>:Hola
```

---

[`System.Text.RegularExpressions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.text.regularexpressions(v=vs.110).aspx) proporcionan acceso al motor de expresiones regulares de .NET

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza la siguiente expresión regular:

```
<Etiqueta>([a-záéíñóúü]+)
```

*Código:*

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<Etiqueta>([a-záéíñóúü]+)";
        string input = @"Hay datos <Etiqueta>que [re]quiero <Etiqueta>Hola que tal";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            list.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }

        string[] Datos = list.ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", Datos));
    }
}
```

*Salida:*

```
que
Hola
```

Ver [*demo*](http://ideone.com/O7WiB4) en línea.

<sub>La extracción se hace con expresiones regulares (véase [regex](/questions/tagged/regex))  La variable `pattern` es utilizada en el método `Matches`. `([a-záéíñoóúü]+)` indica un grupo (de ahí el `m.Groups[1].Value`) cuyo contenido son letras de la `a` a la `z`, vocales acentuadas y otras letras, típicas del idioma español.</sub>