# C# ¿como obtener la palabra que sigue a una palabra especifica?

Tags: c#

quisiera saber como obtener la palabra que sigue a una palabra especifica en un string, (sin saber cual es ni cuantas palabras tiene el string).Ej:

string:"Las aguilas vuelan y los delfines nadan", deseo obtener la palabra inmediatamente posterior a "los", en  este caso "delfines".Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Este sitio no es para que alguien haga tus programas por tí, es para ayudarte en los problemas que te surjan al hacer tus programas. Por eso, escribe en la pregunta el código que has probado(un [mcve]) y el problema específico que te has encontrado, incluyendo datos de entrada, comportamiento esperado y comportamiento observado. Revisa [help] y [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

primero debes separarlas con un split(' '), luego recorrer el array hasta encontrar la palabra específica, haces un next.

```
string palabras = "Las aguilas vuelan y los delfines nadan";
var arr = palabras.split(' ');
bool encontrada = false;
foreach(var palabra in arr){
     if (encontrada)
       {
           return palabra;
       } 
      if (palabra = "los") encontrada = true;
}
```

Comment: Perdon, pero quiero encontrar la palabra que sigue a "los", en este caso "delfines", por supuesto sin saber que es "delfines"

Comment: Ses puede hacer utilizando Regex? o este metodo te parece mas rapido?.Gracias

Comment: Regex es normalmente mejor pero más complicado, este fue el más claro que se me ocurrió... puedes usar linq tambien, pero si no son datos muyyyy grandes o funciones repetitivas no vas a notar mucha diferencia realmente....

Comment: Por favor, evita en el futuro contestar preguntas que no demuestran que se haya intentado algo.

Comment: Ok lo tendré en cuenta para la proxima.... muchas gracias, pero por otro lado no veo mucha diferencia con este planteo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66275/sacar-palabras-de-un-texto?rq=1 salvo que es apenas más complicado (regex o doble bucle).